# Resources.Load is not working when the project is compiled, but works perfecly when it is run through the unity editor

Tags: image, resources

So I am trying to load a .png file from the resources folder under assets. This works perfectly as intended until I compile the game and try to run it the exact same way. I have no idea why.

Here is the code that takes the .png file and assigns it to a texture variable:

```
void getImage(string file)
{


    currTexture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>(file);
    // loads a texture from (Assets/Resources/stringInVariable.png)



    imageSlide.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = currTexture;
    // sets gameobjects raw image components texture as image assigned to the texture variable


    if(currTexture == null)
        // if no other images exist for the program to display as a slide the intro scene will end and the player will load into the intro drop scene before entering the main world space
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("introDrop");
        // loads game intro scene
    }

}
```